# publishing topics and tf data through wireless

Tags: ros, wireless, icreate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I want to have my laptop on a icreate with the lid closed. Hover i also want to visualize it mapping the room using RVIZ.

Is there a way to have the pointcloud topics and tf data published wirelessly so i can view what the create is mapping from a base station.

I would also like to control the create from the base station.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64180/publishing-topics-and-tf-data-through-wireless/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have set up things correctly, it should not matter where rviz (or any other node) runs, as ROS generally uses TCP/IP communication and if nodes are on the same or different computers thus is transparent to ROS. Or that's at least the case in theory.

In the real world, running things on different computers can be a little more tricky, as you want to sync clocks, setup computers so they can talk ROS to each other correctly and have to consider communication bandwidth constraints. The latter is expecially true if you use a wireless link. Many people use ROS like this however and it works well most of the time.

For some basic information you'll likely want to look at [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3